# Python Unwantedly Executes Command on Run

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10

Everyone! I first of all apologize for my lack of coding knowledge, I am currently attempting to learn Python on my own for "fun." My only formal education comes from a high-school Java AP course taken years ago.

I am currently using Python version 3.6 on the Windows 10 operating system, utilizing the PyCharm IDE.

On run my Tkinter GUI based application automatically executes an exit function that I defined under a class. The desired effect is for the window to close only when the user clicks the "terminate" button within the GUI window.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import webbrowser
import tkinter as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

##Application main window setup.
window = ttk.Tk()
window.maxsize(width=200, height=200)
window.minsize(width=200,height=200)
window.config(bg=("black"))
window.title("Hello World")


##Set a 'class' for exit function of application.
class Exit():
##Defines the countdown timer and sets parameters that need to be satisfied before exit.
    def timer(self):
        countdown = 3
        self.x = int
        for self.x in reversed(range(0,countdown + 1)):
            print(self.x)
        ##When 'x' reahces -1 the application exits.
        if self.x > -1:
            print("Bye!")
            window.destroy()
        ##Otherwise a label displaying a text message appears.
        else:
            swell = ttk.Label(text=("'Hello World!'"),bg=("black"),fg=("white"),font=("Times New Roman",12,"bold"))
            swell.place(x=50,y=50)

##Retrieve the defined 'timer' function from the 'Exit' class.
exit=Exit()
exit.timer()

##Button with attahced command to execute the exit of application via user input.
quitButton=ttk.Button(
    window,text=("Terminate"),bg=("red"),fg=("white"),font=("bold"),width=20,height=1,anchor=ttk.S,command=lambda: exit)
quitButton.place(x=6,y=150)



window.mainloop()
```

Any form of help is appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

*As a side  note I can successfully issue a command from a button, however the retrieved function is only one line. It seems I cannot handle multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you are destroying the window in the timer class method. After your for loop, x will equal 0. Therefore it is more than -1, and the window class is destroyed. Quitbutton trys to use window but it has been destroyed.

In the output I assume you are seeing 'Bye'

I got the correct result with the following:

```
import tkinter as ttk
from time import sleep

##Application main window setup.
window = ttk.Tk()
window.maxsize(width=200, height=200)
window.minsize(width=200, height=200)
window.config(bg=("black"))
window.title("Hello World")


##Set a 'class' for exit function of application.
class Exit():
    """
    Defines the countdown timer and sets parameters 
    that need to be satisfied before exit.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.countdown = 3
        swell = ttk.Label(text=("Hello World!"), bg=("black"),
                          fg=("white"), font=("Times New Roman", 12, "bold"))
        swell.place(x=50,y=50)

    def quit(self):
        for iteration in reversed(range(0, self.countdown + 1)):
            print(iteration)
            sleep(1)
        print("Bye!")
        window.destroy()

##Retrieve the defined 'timer' function from the 'Exit' class.
exit=Exit()

##Button with attahced command to execute the exit of application via user input.
quitButton=ttk.Button(
    window,text=("Terminate"), bg=("red"), fg=("white"), font=("bold"),
    width=20, height=1, anchor=ttk.S, command=lambda: exit.quit())
quitButton.place(x=6,y=150)


window.mainloop()
```

You can see here I also used the init method in the exit class. Its a special kind of method which will auto run when the class is initiated.

It didn't require much changing. All I did was move the destroy window function into its own class method and had the second window instance command be set to run this method.

Comment: Yes I get an error read back suggesting the very thing you just said. Not sure how to rectify the issue though. I have tried different variations of the above code and have no issue creating a button that works without the countdown, it is only when I add in that additional layer do the problems arise. I have/had similar a issue when attempting to a load an image on button click. Again it is the multiple lined functions that stump me up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand now. So is it you don't want to have the count down at all? If so you could edit my suggestion to only have the swell variable created.

Comment: No I am sorry, I did not see your answer before posting that comment. Thank you so much for your help. I do want the countdown aspect implemented. I have updated my code to reflect your changes and now the "window.destroy" works as intended via user input, the countdown however, still automatically executes.

Comment: Oh I see what you want. One second I will update the code for the desired goal.

Comment: @Mobious-11 I think I have what you described. If you have any other problems I'll check in tomorrow.

Comment: Again thank you so much! You have been a blessing, it now works perfectly. I have been trying to find a solution for longer than I would like to admit.